# Possible reason for "base table or view not found" when it works locally

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having a strange issue.
On my local machine everything is fine but when I do the same action (a simple select query) on the production system it throws "base table or view not found".
Of course I know what the error means but the table exists and everything should be fine.
I don't have any clue. Any ideas where this could come from or how to fix it?
I'm using laravel 5.4 if it's important.

Comment: let me geuss  locally you are working on windows, and the production system is linux?

Comment: absolutely correct!

Comment: " Any ideas where this could come from or how to fix it?" This looks to be a case sensitivity problem with PHP classes or table names.. Be sure to use correct casing meaning correct uppercase and lowercase text

Comment: I know that linux is case sensitive and windows is not. But as I'm using eloquent (and any other query works) the error seems to be a bit more specific. Shouldn't I get problems with every query and the whole thing wouldn't be working at all?

Comment: please check your `.env` file. maybe its not correct :)

Comment: Could you please post a code example that generates the error?

Comment: "But as I'm using eloquent (and any other query works) the error seems to be a bit more specific. Shouldn't I get problems with every query and the whole thing wouldn't be working at all?" Can´t answer that i don't work with eloquent  and or laravel the other comments where just educated guesses

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this was a stupid mistake.
I had a typo in my validator and mistakenly wrote the table name uppercase.
Thanks for the comments you were absolutely right I just looked at the wrong place.